# Vuetify Datatable: Hide dropdown menu for sorting below mobileBreakpoint with grouping

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Consider following code based on https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#grouping

```js
// Disable annoying tips:
Vue.config.devtools = false
Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      search: '',
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'start',
          value: 'name',
          groupable: false,
        },
        { text: 'Category', value: 'category', align: 'right' },
        { text: 'Dairy', value: 'dairy', align: 'right' },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'dairy', align: 'right' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          category: 'Ice cream',
          dairy: 'Yes',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          category: 'Cookie',
          dairy: 'Yes',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%', 
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          category: 'Pastry',
          dairy: 'Yes',
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '8%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          category: 'Cookie',
          dairy: 'No',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          iron: '16%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          category: 'Candy',
          dairy: 'No',
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          iron: '0%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          category: 'Candy',
          dairy: 'No',
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          iron: '2%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          category: 'Toffee',
          dairy: 'No',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5,
          iron: '45%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          category: 'Pastry',
          dairy: 'Yes',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          iron: '22%',
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          category: 'Candy',
          dairy: 'Yes',
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          iron: '6%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          category: 'Ice cream',
          dairy: 'Yes',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.4.8/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card>
    <v-card-title>
      <v-text-field
        v-model="search"
        append-icon="mdi-magnify"
        label="Search"
        single-line
        hide-details
        ></v-text-field>
    </v-card-title>
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      item-key="name"
      :search="search"
      sort-by="name"
      group-by="category"
      class="elevation-1"
      show-group-by
      mobile-breakpoint=100000
      :header-props="{'disable-sort': true}"
    ></v-data-table>
      </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.4.8/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Click `Run code snippet` and on `Full page` to see it better.

If you prefer codepen, click [here](https://codepen.io/Hotschke/pen/vYgKepV?editors=1010).

I have enforced the mobile/responsive version of the [`<v-data-table>`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/) component of [vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/) by setting [`mobile-breakpoint`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#props-mobile-breakpoint) to `100000`. The default is `600` which corresponds to the [breakpoint](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/breakpoints/) `xs`.

I would like to hide the dropdown menu for sorting for the mobile view but leave sorting active for grouping functionality and also for Desktop/Tablet viewer.

I have added

```
:disable-sort="$vuetify.breakpoint.xsOnly"
// or here simply since we consider only the mobile version:
disable-sort
```

However, this breaks the grouping.

Other tries were

1. `:hide-default-header="$vuetify.breakpoint.xsOnly"`
   which removes the description of the entries which I do not want.
2. `:header-props="{'disable-sort': true}"` which does nothing

Vuetify version: 2.4.8 with Vue 2.6.12.

**UPDATE** Clarification that the column headers should stay but only the dropdown for sorting in the responsive view should be removed:

[image]

Comment: Just to undertsand your requirement better, You just need to remove the sort dropdown for mobile devices, am I right here

Comment: @chans Your comment is correct: ONLY the dropdown for mobile devices.

Comment: please find the below answer and let me know if this solves your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done a very good try, but the behaviour is little different here

The mobile breakpoint scope is within the table and it doen't mutate the device type in **this.$vuetify.breakpoint**, so when you check this.$vuetify.breakpoint.xsOnly it will return true only if the screen width is less than 600 and not 10000
even if you want to confirm the same , you can put **this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name** inside a span tag in UI, you will get **xs** only if the screen width is less than 600

> If you want to hide the sort_by if the device width is less than
> 10000, it is possible to manage by css

Please find the code below

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card>
    <v-card-title>
      <v-text-field
        v-model="search"
        append-icon="mdi-magnify"
        label="Search"
        single-line
        hide-details
        ></v-text-field>
    </v-card-title>
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      item-key="name"
      :search="search"
      sort-by="name"
      group-by="category"
      class="elevation-1"
      show-group-by
    ></v-data-table>
      </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .v-data-table-header.v-data-table-header-mobile {
   display:none; 
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      search: '',
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'start',
          value: 'name',
          groupable: false,
        },
        { text: 'Category', value: 'category', align: 'right' },
        { text: 'Dairy', value: 'dairy', align: 'right' },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'dairy', align: 'right' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          category: 'Ice cream',
          dairy: 'Yes',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          category: 'Cookie',
          dairy: 'Yes',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%', 
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          category: 'Pastry',
          dairy: 'Yes',
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '8%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          category: 'Cookie',
          dairy: 'No',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          iron: '16%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          category: 'Candy',
          dairy: 'No',
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          iron: '0%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          category: 'Candy',
          dairy: 'No',
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          iron: '2%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          category: 'Toffee',
          dairy: 'No',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5,
          iron: '45%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          category: 'Pastry',
          dairy: 'Yes',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          iron: '22%',
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          category: 'Candy',
          dairy: 'Yes',
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          iron: '6%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          category: 'Ice cream',
          dairy: 'Yes',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

> Please find the working codepen here:
> https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/WNRxWwz?editors=1010

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, `hide-default-header="isMobileBreakpoint"` removes also the column headers which I do not want. See update of my question.

Comment: @Hotschke, please find the update answer, hope it solves your issue

Comment: Thanks for your update. It works as I asked. I was suspecting that this can only be achieved via css.